# order by second word in title?

Tags: title, order, query-string

I have full names as title posts and want to order it by the surname.

How could i do this with wordpress?

in PHP it would be along the lines of -

```
 SELECT * from posts ORDER BY SUBSTR(LTRIM(post_title), LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(post_title)))
```

current code getting people category is;

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>50,
    'cat'=> '39,-41',
    'orderby'=>'title',
    'order'=>'ASC',
);
query_posts($args);
```

how can i get that second word order?

best, Dan.

Comment: Great question—wish I could upvote it twice.

Comment: Couldn't you use a Custom Select Query? http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query I need to do the same thing. Will see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

There is a filter, 'posts_orderby', which allows you to specify your own ORDER BY clauses. In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'order_by_surname' );

function order_by_surname( $orderby, $query ) {

    // first you should check to make sure sure you're only filtering the particular query
    // you want to hack. return $orderby if its not the correct query;

    return "ORDER BY SUBSTR(
        LTRIM({$wpdb->posts}.post_title), 
        LOCATE(' ',LTRIM({$wpdb->posts}.post_title)))";

}
```

Comment: thanks - but how would i apply that to only this query_posts? D.

Comment: 2 ways - (1 - more hackish): add this filter right before running the query, remove it afterward. (2 - slightly better) at the beginning of the filter function, check the $query object for variables which are only set in this particular query and return the original $orderby if they're not there.

Comment: This now ends up with a 404 error. WordPress must have changed since 2011. It always gives an error about the $query parameter being missing.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is an SQL query, there is no native WordPress function that does this.

So that leaves you with some PHP options, [explode it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), along with [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) (or ksort) to then arrange the array alphabetically.

This is a very odd way to use this type of data, it should be in a meta box, since you basically have to hack the query in your case to get what you want.

Comment: we're doing a mass import and everything is in the title field. Rather try this in wordpress than excel! Also keeps it easier to manage for the client...

Comment: WordPress supports custom fields for exactly this, honestly using the title is a horribly bad idea, http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: I agree with this approach in general, especially if you're doing a mass import. It should be a trivial task to set a custom field with the last word of the title when importing your posts.